# LD_RUN_PATH equivalent for AIX

Tags: aix

Is there an environment variable equivalent in AIX for $LD_RUN_PATH ?

I am trying to include /usr/lib in the default search path of shared libraries of my program, but I don't want to modify LIBPATH (LD_LIBRARY_PATH equivalent for AIX).

Comment: /usr/lib most likely already is included into the search path. Actually, do you wish to change the linker's behaviour or that of the loader?

Comment: I want to change just the linker's behaviour so that it includes /usr/lib, because at the moment my LIBPATH is set to a list of 3rd party libs and does not include /usr/lib. The compiler seems to include LIBPATH in the program's search list and so /usr/lib is omitted.

Comment: Just add linker-option `-L/usr/lib` (but I do think it is the default). Unless you want to change the _loader's_ behavior via a linker-option. That would be `-blibpath`